# Is it wrong to use these adverbs 'a bit, a little, too' with adjectives 'good, nice, cheap, clean, new, comfortable.'

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I was looking through an English book and came across a rule that has confused me; I dont remember reading it anywhere before(but I am not that well read anyway);

**Don't use these adverbs(a bit, a little, too) with these adjectives-good, nice, cheap, clean, new, comfortable.**

I haven't been able to find something about this on the net. If anyone here can shed some light on it, that would be great!

edit: Name of the book is, 'English Result Pre intermediate student's book, Mark Hancock and Annie McDonald, Oxford University Press'. In a lesson on adverbs of degree, there is an exercise where students have to match Rules with examples: The above rule matches with 'They're a bit nice'. There is a cross next to this sentence suggesting that this is wrong usage.

```
12  Match the rules with the examples
Rules
        1  Put enough after the adjective.
        2  Put the adverbs of degree before the adjective
        3  Don’t use the  adverbs with  adjectives:
    good   nice   cheap   clean   new   comfortable 

Examples
a  It’s very small  ✓
b  They’re a bit nice ✗
c   It’s big enough ✓
```

adverbs in the above exercise are - 'a bit, a little, too'

edit: this is the page in the book to give the context, maybe I have missed some detail [image]
Couldn't get it right side up, sorry about that.

Comment: English Result Pre intermediate student's book, Mark Hancock and Annie McDonald, Oxford University Press. Its a lesson on adverbs of degree. There is an exercise where students have to match Rules with examples: The above rule matches with 'They're a bit nice'. There is a cross next to this sentence suggesting that this is wrong usage.

Comment: @JasperLoy got it, Thanks, I have added the details.

Comment: "A bit" and "a little " are not adverbs. I suggest you get a better book!

Comment: Any book which demands that I no longer speak colloquial English is either _too good_ for the likes of me or _too nice_ for my way of speaking. Maybe the book is a _bit cheap_ for my bookshelves and maybe I would not be _too comfortable_ with it in my house.

Comment: @BillJ I  thought nice being an adjective, **a bit*** is modifying it and hence adverb. 
    'They’re a bit nice.'

Comment: Jimms, I'm sorry to say that "a bit nice" reveals more about the writer than his meaning. Could you run the same idea through two or three other books, please?

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between grammar and style. Grammar lends itself to rules (but bear in mind that the people who formulate such rules are fighting a losing battle with the changes in a living language) whereas style is a matter of opinion (but opinion can be informed by style guides, of which there are many not all in agreement with each other).

You will probably find that there are native speakers who agree with your book that those words should not be used together. That is purely style, not grammar.  If you want to use them, go ahead: you will not for that reason sound like some ignorant foreigner if you do.

Comment: so what I understand from your answer is that its not a grammar rule, purely a matter of style. Thanks a lot for answering. I would be happy if I find this rule mentioned in some book or site, even if its old.

Answer (score -1):

It's definitely more of a style than question of grammar. *However*, keep in mind there are some real reasons for not using those "adverbs" (I am not positive they are actual adverbs).

A state of being **clean** or **new** is one way or another. Either it is clean or dirty, new or used, and it's same with being pregnant or not pregnant. No one is *a bit* pregnant!

While 'cheap' is somewhat relative (someone who makes $40/hr. may think one thing cheap, and the person making $15/hr. may think it is expensive), let's remove that relativity and assume you and your friend/partner/mother/father/etc. have the same definition of cheap and expensive. While it's not technically wrong, it's acceptable in conversational English, but not really correct if one were writing a book or a paper (unless it's in the form of dialogue between characters).

*Good, nice,* and *comfortable* are less definitive (not as "black and white") as clean, new, or cheap, so they are more accepted in conversational and even written English. However, in a formal paper (essay, thesis, etc.) or a published book, it is not really stylistically accepted, because it is more colloquial English than "proper" (textbook) English -- however, again in a dialog between 2 characters, it is more acceptable.

Comment: One thing can’t be cleaner than another, or newer than another?